Non-commutator of symmetries of a Lagrangian giving rise to gauge symmetry
If there are two symmetries of a Lagrangian, perhaps they are transformations, $A$ and $B$, and they don't commute $[A, B] \neq 0.$ Let this act on some field, then if $(BA)^{-1}AB$ does not return the original field, i.e. if  $(BA) ^{-1}AB \neq I$, then this gives rise to a new symmetry so it will have an associated charge/current  by Noether's theorem.
I feel like this is a common occurrence but I can't find any references on considering this as a symmetry/computing an associated conserved charge/current.
Is there certain terminology/framework I need to be searching for?

For starters, gauge "symmetry" is not a real symmetry, and as such has no conserved charge associated to it.

Hi sars909. Welcome to Phys.SE. Are you talking about the commutator in group theory rather than ring theory?

You are badly and dangerously conflating the group commutator with the Lie algebra commutator, no?
